# How to get actual line from javascript error line number

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling

The line # isn't so useful when your page is dynamically generated.  What I'd really like is the actual offending line.

Is there some way of doing this?  Perhaps

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML.Split('\n')[lineNumber-1];

// OR

document.body.innerHTML.Split('\n')[lineNumber-1];
```

However, when I tested it in `Firefox 10`, I got that the above were inaccurate unless the `html` and `body` tags were on the same line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)?

Comment: That's one of the reasons why I keep all my js code in external files!

Comment: Also, sometimes a syntax error in the line above can cause an error in a subsequent line. So line-numbers are a useful guide, but aren't always accurate.

Comment: the purpose of this would be to support automatic logging, so no firebug :-P  Shouldn't this be not difficult, regardless of what the intent is?

Comment: @David Thomas:  but at least it'd be a start.  I could also pick a range around the line to log, but it would still be useful for that range to be accurate.

Comment: @bfavaretto: that may be the better way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is curious, the answer for me was to make the number of lines above the first `head` or `body` element consistent across all pages.

For me this magic # is three.

One should note though that if the error occurred in a js file, then I don't know how to get the actual line client-side.  However, since the whole point of this was to log the line to the server (using ajax), I could simply read the line of the js file on the server.  So it means that you have to ad an extra check on the url of the error to see that it is or is not a javascript file.